# Using Windows credentials with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, authentication, tortoise-svn, ntlm

We are a bunch of Subversion users logging in on our Windows computers with Windows domain accounts.
I can set up a Subversion server on another machine in the same domain.  I want to use our Windows accounts to control Subversion repository access with TortoiseSVN.  Thus far I've tried the free version of VisualSVN, which works for that purpose, except that TortoiseSVN keeps prompting for the usernames and passwords and I don 't want them to be stored on disk.  VisualSVN Enterprise promises to fix it but its price tag is a problem for us.

Are there any alternative solutions to using our Windows domain accounts with a Subversion server?  Have you used them yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding mod_auth_sspi to your Apache system (VisualSVN is Apache under the mmc snapin covers) then [that should work](http://old.nabble.com/TortoiseSVN-with-NTLM-not-working-after-reading-FAQs-%28PROPFIND-401%29-td15480981.html), note you'll have to use https connections - not http.